# Why static block is not executed

Tags: java, static-block, classloading

As per java doc, static block is executed when the class is initialized.

Could anyone please tell me why static block is not executed when I run below code?

```
class A {
    static {
        System.out.println("Static Block");
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void example1() {
        Class<?> class1 = A.class;
        System.out.println(class1);
    }


    public static void example2() {
        try {
            Class<?> class1 = Class.forName("ClassLoading_Interview_Example.ex1.A");
            System.out.println(class1);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        example1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A class's static initialization normally happens immediately before
>   the first time one of the following events occur:
>
> - an instance of the class is created,
> - a static method of the class is invoked,
> - a static field of the class is assigned,
> - a non-constant static field is used, or  [...]

You are currently not doing any of the above.
So, by replacing

```
Class<?> class1 = A.class;
System.out.println(class1);
```

with this for example

```
A object = new A();
```

will give you your result.

Comment: So what happens when i execute this line "Class<?> class1 = A.class;". Would not the JVM load class A?

Comment: @SridharSrinivasan If you execute this line the JVM will load the class, but will not initialize it as a class initialization happens according to a set of rules (see my quote above) and this is not included in those rules.

Answer (score 2):

Referencing `A.class` will not resulting in executing `A`'s static initializers, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)

> Initialization of a class consists of executing its static
>   initializers and the initializers for static fields (class variables)
>   declared in the class.

And

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the
>   first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> T is a class and an instance of T is created.
>
> A static method declared by T is invoked.
>
> A static field declared by T is assigned.
>
> A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant
>   variable (§4.12.4).