# Value of static variable not changed even after initializing the child class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, jvm, static-variables, static-block

When I invoke the static variable `y` by using `Checks.y` (`Checks` being a subclass), the static block is not executed and the value of `y` doesn't get updated.

```
class Par {
    static int y = 4;
}

class Checks extends Par {
    static {
        y = 5;
    }
}

public class Check {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Checks.y); // here printing 4
    }
}
```

As static is shared among all subclasses, the value is supposed to be updated.

What could be the reason behind it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The field `y` is not declared by class `Checks`.

Reading static fields doesn't trigger initialization of the referenced class (`Checks`), unless that class is the one in which the field is declared (see JLS quote below). In this example, even if `y` is accessed through `Checks`, that will only trigger the initialization of `Par` because `Par` is the class declaring `y`.

In other words, the class `Checks` is in a sense not used at runtime.

This is perhaps one illustration of why it's wrong to access `static` members through subclasses, something that causes a compile-time warning.

---

There's a simple explanation in [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html):

> **12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs**
>
> A class or interface type T will be
>   initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the
>   following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - A static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant
>     variable (§4.12.4).
> - T is a top level class (§7.6) and an assert statement (§14.10)
>     lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.
>     
>     ...
>     
>   A reference to a static field (§8.3.1.1) causes initialization of only the class or interface that actually declares it, even though it might be referred to through the name of a subclass, a subinterface, or a class that implements an interface.

The last note explains why your subclass is not being initialized.

Comment: Thanks! I missed the point that initialization occurs only if the static field is declared by the "Check"(child) class itself!  If I would have declared y as static in child class then the child's y hides the parent's( Par ) y?

Comment: You mean Checks or really Check?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Thanks, I meant `Checks`. The class names were changed at some point and I got it wrong while editing.

Comment: @rawat Yes, the child's field would hide the parent's. It's another bad thing to redeclare field names in subclasses, for many reasons similar to this. If you need the field to be reassigned while the child class is being initialized, then maybe the best option is to acces the value through a static method in the subclass

Comment: @ernest_k Thanks, I actually meant "Checks" as it is the child class of "Par" class, BTW ..sorry for the typo!

Answer (score 9):

From [JLS 12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1):

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the
>   first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).
> - T is a top level class (§7.6), and an assert statement (§14.10) lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.

Since y is not declared in checks, none of the above criteria is satisfied.

Another way to illustrate this behavior:

```
class par {
    static int y = 4;
    static {
        System.out.println("static constructor of par");
    }
}

class checks extends par {
    static int x = 6;
    static {
        System.out.println("checks static constructor");
        y = 5;
    }
}

public class check{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(checks.y);
        System.out.println(checks.x);
        System.out.println(checks.y);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
static constructor of par
4
checks static constructor
6
5
```

So after invoking `checks.x` that satisfies the second rule, the static constructor gets invoked.

Answer (score 4):

That's because the `static` block in the `checks` class doesn't get executed. Although you mention the class `checks` the JVM doesn't load it at all.

You can confirm this by adding another `System.out.println` inside the static block.

```
class checks extends par {

    static {
        System.out.println("Test");
        y = 5;
    }
}
```

The word `Test` will never get printed.

---

Read the section [**12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) of the Java Language Specification to know more.

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
System.out.println(checks.y); // Here printing 4
```

`y` refers to a field of the `par` class. This field access results into the loading of the `par` class (the parent class) according to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) (emphasis is mine):

> 12.4. Initialization of Classes and Interfaces
>
> ....
>
> 12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs
>
> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the
>   first occurrence of any one of the following:
>     T is a class and an instance of T is created.   A static method
>   declared by T is invoked.
>
> A static field declared by T is assigned.
>
> **A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant
>   variable (§4.12.4).**
>
> T is a top level class (§7.6) and an assert statement (§14.10)
>   lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.

But it doesn't load the `checks` class because (emphasis is mine) :

> **A reference to a static field (§8.3.1.1) causes initialization of only
>   the class or interface that actually declares it**, even though it might
>   be referred to through the name of a subclass, a subinterface, or a
>   class that implements an interface.

Answer (score 2):

The one aspect not mentioned so far that might be confusing to new Java programmers: the fact how you organize your source code doesn't matter to a certain degree!

You have your two classes (which should be name Parent and Child btw to follow Java naming conventions) in one file, or one piece of example. So you probably assume: these things come together automatically at runtime.

But at runtime, there are individual class files per class. And as the others have said: nothing in the code references the child class. Thus that class isn't loaded, thus the assignment doesn't occur!

Answer (score 0):

As others mention, the static block isn't executed because the class isn't initialized as [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49316560/why-static-block-is-not-executed).

Notice the class convention names start with an upper case letter.

A clearer example to show Overriding class isn't used:

```
class Par {
    static int y = 4;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Checks.y);    // Here printing 4
        System.out.println(new Checks().y);    // Here printing 5
    }
}

class Checks extends Par {
   static {
        y = 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As per your example, the class Check's static block never get called. Static blocks are always run before the object is created. If you add checks, `object = new checks()`, in your Check class you should see the expected value.

Comment: "Check static block never get called." is just describing problem in question using different words. Real question is "why it isn't executed here".

Comment: "Static blocks are always run before the object is created" is unclear, do you mean that it happens every time before creating each object?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a variant of how you force the initialization of `Checks` class.

```
class Par {
    static int y = 4;
}

class Checks extends Par {
    public static int x;
    static {
        y = 5;
    }
}

 class Check {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(checks.y); // Prints 4
        System.out.println(checks.x); // Prints 0
        System.out.println(checks.y); // Prints 5
    }
}
```